# How to change style of a Navlink's children element in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a **NavLink** element where its changes it's color when it is **active** like this:

`<NavLink to='/dashboard' className='dashboardicon' activeClassName='dashboardicon_coloured'>`

What I am trying to do is change the style of its **children** element (img), when **NavLink** is **active**. Its positioned like this:

```
   <NavLink to='/..' className='..' activeClassName='..'>
     <img  //change style here on active?  />
   </NavLink>
```

It throws some kind of an error because it's not inside NavLink, anyone can think of a solution? This question hasn't been asked much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `CSS` for this,

```
.dashboardicon.dashboardicon_coloured img{
    width: 100px
    //other style here
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of it! I thought you can't change a css class after activeClassName is set. This solved my problem. Thank you so much!